# How to set batch-normalization op in inference mode without calling tf.layers.batch_normalization() ?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, deep-residual-networks

I define a deep CNN with tensorflow, inluding a batch-normalization op, i.e, my code may look like this:

```
def network(input):
    ...
    input = tf.layers.batch_normalization(input, ...)
    ...
```

Assume the network has been trained, and the checkpoint file has been saved. Now I would like to use this model for inference. Normally, I can call the function `network(input)` again, except for passing parameter `training=False` to `tf.layers.batch_normalization()`, then restore weights from the checkpoint file.

However, I would prefer to use `tf.import_meta_graph` to rebuild my network, since the code in function `network(input)` can be changed.

But now how I can set the batch-normalization op in inference mode this time? Since I have no access to function `tf.layers.batch_normalization()`, it's a little difficult for me to work this out.

Comment: Check out [graph transforms](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#fold_batch_norms).  In particular, fold_batch_norms.